# React Native: ListView renders before dataSource being set

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Listview tries to render, before the datasource is set (ComponentDidMount)
So it's always empty. if i try to call loadData() it will show it then.

How can i avoid component rendering before loading finishes?

Actions :

```js
export const GET_COURSES = 'GET_COURSES';
export const GET_COURSES_FAILED = 'GET_COURSES_FAILED';

import getCoursesAPI from '../common/Functions';

export const getCourses = (users) => {
  return dispatch => {
    getCoursesAPI(users)
    .then((data)=>{
      const {courseList, lectureList} = data;
      return dispatch(coursesSuccess(courseList, lectureList));
    })
    .catch(()=>{
      return dispatch(coursesFailed());
    });
  };
}

const coursesSuccess = (courses, lectures) => {
  return {
    type: GET_COURSES,
    payload: {
      courses,
      lectures
    }
  }
};

const coursesFailed = () => {
  return {
    type: GET_COURSES_FAILED
  }
};
```

Reducer :

```js
import * as types from "./courses.actions";

export const INITIAL_STATE = {
  courses: {}
};

export default function courses(state = INITIAL_STATE, action){
  const {courses, lectures} = state;
  switch(action.type){
    case types.GET_COURSES:
    return {
      ...state,
      courses: action.payload.courses,
      lectures: action.payload.lectures
    };
    case types.GET_COURSES_FAILED:
    return {
      ...state,
      courses: courses ,
      lectures: lectures
    };
    default:
    return state;
  }
}
```

Component itself :

```js
export default class Courses extends Component {
 static propTypes = {
  user: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    users: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  courseDetails: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  courses: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    getCourses: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    openProfile: PropTypes.func.isRequired
 };

 constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
          dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({
            rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2,
          }),
          dataLoaded: 0
      };
    }

 componentWillMount(){

 }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.props.getCourses(this.props.users);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
    const courses = newProps.courses.courses[this.props.user]
    this.setState({
        dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(courses),
        dataLoaded: courses.length
    });
  }


 render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ height: Platform.OS == "ios" ? height - 114 : height - 130 }}>
        <ListView
          dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
          renderRow={this.renderRow.bind(this)}
        />
      </View>
    );
 }
}
```

UPDATE
@stinodes :
[image]

This fixes the issue but i think its not the proper way to do it :

```js
componentWillMount(){
    setTimeout(()=>{
      console.log('!run!');
      this.loadData();
    }, 1000);
 }

  componentDidMount(){

  }


  async loadData(){
    const {user, users, getCourses, courses} = this.props;
    await getCourses(users);
    const data = courses[user];
    this.setState({
      dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(data),
      dataLoaded: data.length
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `componentWillMount`-hook instead of the `componentDidMount`.
Using the first, sets it before the render. The latter fires after the component is rendered for the first time.

---

**edit**: Since you're using redux to update your global state and then get your data passed into your props, you will want to fetch your courses when your component mounts. You have this in place, by loading your data in the `componentDidMount`-hook.
However, you won't need the `async` keyword, since redux will be passing the courses through your component's props anyway.

When your component's props are updated, it will do a rerender as well. If you want to have your `dataSource` in your state, you can use the `componentWillReceiveProps`-hook. This hook will be fired when your component receives new properties.
When this is called, you can add your populated datasource to your state. This **won't** cause a new render.

Example:

```
class Courses extends Component {
    /* ... */

    componentDidMount() {

        // Will fetch your data asynchronously
        this.props.getCourses(this.props.users);

    }

    // This hook gets the new props passed. Old props are
    // still available in this.props
    componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {

        const courses = newProps.courses.courses[this.props.user]
        this.setState({
            dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(courses),
            dataLoaded: courses.length
        })

    }

    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately It didn't help.

Comment: @Ataomega I overlooked the fact that your load data is async. Are you sure you are actually getting data back from your `getCourses`? Also, you might as well make that function return the courses instead of getting it from the props afterwards, since you're using `async` anyway.

Comment: Yes it returns data. But i need to get data from props. it's redux. and set dataSource for listview

Comment: @Ataomega I edited my answer based on the fact that you're using Redux. Let me know if it helped out or if you're still running into problems. You might want to remove some of the bloat code from your question and add some of your data-loading code instead (like your actions and reducer).

Comment: I've updated the question. Unfortunately what you said, also didn't help.

Comment: @Ataomega seems like you're running into an error when fetching and setting your data to your global state. Can you add some of your reducer and action-creator code to the question as well?

Comment: I've updated the question again, that was my mistake. because i've changed it from courses.courses to only courses. now there is no errors. there is no error while fetching data. still listview is being rendered before data comes in. actions and reducers are added to question

Comment: I'd assume your `coursesList` your get back is an array? Your `initialState` defines `courses` as an object though. Might want to fix that. If your `coursesList` is not an array, then it should be.

Comment: coursesList is an Object. Keys are userIds and values are Arrays of courses. Won't it work like that?

Comment: newProps.courses is an object and newProps.courses[newProps.user] an array. is that wrong?

Comment: No, it should be fine. Are you sure that it's not just the `ListView` having no height?  
Try adding `flex: 1` to the list's styles, to make sure it actually has height. For all you know, it might be populated, but just not showing.

Comment: I think it cant be the UI. it was working before implementing redux. adding a button which calls loadData, will bring the data and rerender the listview but putting some function in ComponentDidmount or willreceiveprops doesnt work. ( grabs the data, but view is not rerendered)

Comment: setting timeout at component did mount fixes the issue, but i think it's not a good idea >>>> setTimeout(()=>{
      this.loadData();
    }, 2000);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134068/discussion-between-stinodes-and-ataomega).